# JavaScript Count Down Timer Repeat using server time

Tags: javascript, timer

so I'm trying to create a timer to count down every 12 hrs based on my web host Time Zone (GMT+10), for example, amount of time till 12am than once 12am passes how long till 12pm and so on. I currently have some code but I believe it only counts down 24 hrs...

```
setInterval(function time(){
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = 24 - d.getHours();
  var min = 60 - d.getMinutes();
  if((min + '').length == 1){
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  var sec = 60 - d.getSeconds();
  if((sec + '').length == 1){
        sec = '0' + sec;
  }
  jQuery('#the-final-countdown p').html(hours+':'+min+':'+sec)
}, 1000);
```

Oh and a quick little bonus question... If possible would any one know (if their is any way to make this timer) when the timer reaches 00:00:00 to display text for 30 seconds than resume the count down?

Comment: Java != javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, %12 will make it reach 0 two times a day.

Should be 23 and 59, not 24 and 60 because  counting start from 0

```js
setInterval(function time(){
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = (23 - d.getHours())%12;
  var min = 59 - d.getMinutes();
  var sec = 59 - d.getSeconds();


    if(min===59&&sec>30&&hours===11){
  min=0;
  sec=0;
  hours=0;
  //and show what you want for 30 seconds
  

  }
   if((min + '').length === 1){
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  
  if((sec + '').length === 1){
        sec = '0' + sec;
  }
  jQuery('p').html(hours+':'+min+':'+sec)
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Hey, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but it outputs https://gyazo.com/14ef0a16db5fb5897a51b4570ea6e6e0

Comment: I've edited the answer, sorry about that, it need another '='

Comment: Hey, so I have modifed the code to implement a few custom ideas although doing so I have broken the code... Do you think you could look over and see if you know what I stuffed up XD <3 https://hastebin.com/axiyorires.lisp

Comment: On a first look you used '=' and not '===' in some if statements.
Make sure you know the difference [link](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/558ea4f5e39efed371000508)

Comment: Ok so I have changed the if statements to include '===' but yet still I only get '0HR 0MIN'????? https://hastebin.com/coqucozuse.js

Comment: I ran your modified code and works "6hrs37Min".
 FYI 0HR 0MIN should print if you didn't change the '=', make sure you reload the file

Comment: Yea ok that's embarrassing... Thanks for all your help Cristian :) <3